# npm ERR! errno -5

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native

hi i am getting this error when I try typical starter command with react native

```
react-native init test
```

returns this error

```
npm WARN react-native@0.44.0 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.6 but none was installed.
Setting up new React Native app in /Users/xxxx/ReactNativeProjects/gpss
Installing React...
gpss@0.0.1 /Users/xxxxx/ReactNativeProjects/gpss
└── react@16.0.0-alpha.6 

Installing Jest...
npm ERR! code EIO
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! EIO: i/o error, read
```

Comment: Could be an issue with 0.44. Have you tried using 0.43?

Comment: I/O errors may point to hardware issues (HDD/SSD).

Comment: yesterday it was working , and how can I downgrade to 0.43, I remember upgraded yesterday maybe it

Comment: please edit the answer in your question or accept an answer to close this question

Answer (score 0):

You could uninstall `react-native` and then use the following command:

`npm install react@reactversion --save`.

Note (reactversion) is your desired version you want to have.

You could also just try reinstalling it as:

`npm install react --save`

Or upgrade with:

`npm update react-native`

---

Eventually cleaning the cache worked out fine. Hope this answer solves any user's problem in the future.

Comment: it installs react automaticly no problem, but  how can I uninstall?

Comment: `npm uninstall -g react`??? it's how you installed it, just put `uninstall` there

Comment: npm WARN react-native@0.44.0 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.6 but none was installed.
Setting up new React Native app in /Users/barron9/test3
Installing React...
test3@0.0.1 /Users/barron9/test3
└── react@16.0.0-alpha.6 

Installing Jest...
⸨     ░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠴ fetchMetadata: verb afterAdd /Users/barron9/.npm/has-flag/1.0.0/package/package.json written

Comment: Installing Jest...
npm ERR! code EIO
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! EIO: i/o error, read

Comment: what have you typed?

Comment: so it can't install jest individually npm install jest not working...$ npm install jest
npm ERR! code EIO
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! EIO: i/o error, read

Comment: `npm install react@16.0.0-alpha.6` you're missing this one. Make sure to install it at the correct path as well.

Comment: after init it installs 16 alpha 6 automaticly...................... but when installing jest it gets error

Comment: you installed jest using `npm install --save-dev jest`?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem on Windows, using Virtual Studio Code. I uninstalled an unrelated program shortly before the error and I suspect that was the cause. So I restarted my PC and updated Windows and the npm errors were gone. Everything is working and disaster averted.

Try closing background tasks, updating and/or restarting your computer.